# Change SQL where clause based on a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to alter a query to do something like this (following is generic pseudo-code):

```
if (tag list contains all tags in the database) {
    select every product regardless of tag, even products with null tag
}
else { //tag list is only a few tags long
    select only the products that have a tag in the tag list
}
```

I have tried doing stuff like this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT p.Id
FROM Tags t
    JOIN Products p ON p.TagId = t.Id
WHERE ((EXISTS(select Id from Tags EXCEPT select item from dbo.SplitString(@tagList,',')) AND p.TagId in (select item from dbo.SplitString(@tagList,',')))
    OR (p.TagId in (select item from dbo.SplitString(@tagList,',')) or p.TagId is null))
```

This will take place inside of a large query with a large WHERE clause, so putting two slightly different queries in an IF ELSE statement is not ideal.

What should I do to get this working?

Comment: Can you execute an anonymous block instead of single statement?

Comment: Do you have a list of all tags in the database? Is there such a table?

Comment: How exactly do you expect to populate `@tagList`? And why do you use a scalar variable rather than a table? Would it not be inefficient to "fill" a scalar variable with all possible tag values in order to "select everything"? Typically we use special "flag" values (usually NULL) to allow the query to ignore a filter and include everything. Suggest you give Erland's entire website a look but esp. the discussion of [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: @Charlieface there is a Tag table, and a product can have a single TagId, which is a FK to the Tag table. so, `select * from Tags` would list all of the Tags in the database.

Comment: OK have fixed my answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: you should use properly normalized input parameters. Ideally this would be a Table-Valued parameter, however if you cannot do that then you could insert the split values into a table variable

```sql
DECLARE @tags TABLE (TagId int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @tags (TagId)
SELECT item
FROM dbo.SplitString(@tagList, ',');
```

Next, the easiest way is probably to just find out first whether all tags match, and store that in a variable.

```sql
DECLARE @isAllTags bit = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT t.Id
    FROM Tags t
    EXCEPT
    SELECT tList.Id
    FROM @tags tList
) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;

SELECT p.Id
FROM Products p
WHERE @isAllTags = 1
  OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM @tags tList
      WHERE tList.TagId = p.TagId);
```

You could merge these queries, but it's unlikely to be more performant.

You could even do it in a very set-based fashion, but it's probably going to be really slow

```sql
SELECT p.Id
FROM Products p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM Tags t
  LEFT JOIN @tags tList ON tList.TagId = t.Id
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN p.TagId = tList.TagId THEN 1 END )) v(ProductMatch)
  HAVING COUNT(t.Id) = COUNT(tList.TagId)  -- all exist
      OR COUNT(v.ProductMatch) > 0              -- at least one match
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this might work.

```sql
SELECT p.Id
FROM 
    Products p LEFT JOIN
    Tags t  ON p.TagId = t.Id
WHERE 
    t.Id is null
    OR
    (t.id is not null and 
        t.Id in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tagList, ',')))
```

I just tested - works

Comment: In this case, t.Id is never null.  I gave this a try and it did not work.

Comment: @RyanB `left join` guarantees that when there are no matching records, it will be null. Your try only suggests that in your database each left record has a matching record. I created fiddle in my DB on existing data (I changed column names) and it worked